# Plot.ly Graph Arduino Uno stopped at "Sending HTTP Post to plotly"

Tags: arduino, ethernet, plotly

I am trying to set up my a temperature module using this walkthrough: [LINK](http://www.instructables.com/id/Plotly-Arduino-Data-Visualization/?ALLSTEPS)

I am doing everything exactly to a T and when I upload the sketch, the serial monitor only goes as far as :

```
.. Initializing ethernet
... Initializing ethernet
... Done initializing ethernet
... Attempting to connect to plotly's REST servers
... Connected to plotly's REST servers
... Sending HTTP Post to plotly
```

Do I need to do something to the MAC address or the IP? This is all over ethernet.

Thank you in advanced.